# Find all instances of string between two other strings that are on other lines

Tags: regex, linux, grep

So I feel like I should know how to do this but I can't quite get it.

I'm trying to find all instances (in all files) where a string that ends with _START exists between two strings (that are normally on other lines) @GROUP and @END_GROUP

So there might be some code like this

```
// @GROUP GroupName OtherStuff
#define GROUPNAME_START 1
#define GROUPNAME_FOO 2
.... (more defines)
#define GROUPNAME_END 10
// @END_GROUP

#define GROUPTWO_START 1
// @GROUP GroupTwo MoreStuff
#define GROUPTWO_FOO 2
.... (some defines)
#define GROUPTWO_BAR 70
// @END_GROUP
```

And I would want to match the first group (really just the line with _START, but everything would be ok) but not the second group or the _START line that is outside of the @GROUP comments.

I figure using grep for this would be the best way to search through all the files, but I can't quite get the regex needed. Thanks for the help.

edit: My bad for not making it clear that I want to be able to search through files in multiple directories at the same time, doing the same as a grep -r "foo" * . Answers have been good, I just didn't make that clear.

edit2: Multiple great answers each solved it in a slightly different way and I really don't know which one would be best. I marked the one who responded first, but anyone looking at this should be sure to check out all the answers, one might be better for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` only sees one line, so it doesn't know whether it's between the group comments or not. `sed` can use addresses, though:

```
sed '/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/!d' input_file | grep '_START'
```

`!` negates the addresses, `d` deletes a line, i.e. we're telling `sed` to remove lines that are not between the group comments. `grep` then operates only on the "interesting" lines.

To make it work for subdirectories, too, add `find` to the toolbox:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec sed '/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/!d' {} + | grep '_START'
```

Or, if the group comment could appear without the corresponding END, use a slower but safer

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec sed '/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/!d' {} \; | grep '_START'
```

Or, let `xargs` operate on the output of `grep -l`:

```
grep -lr @GROUP /path/to/dir | xargs sed '/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/!d' | grep '_START'
```

Note: If your filenames contain spaces, it wouldn't work.

Comment: This works perfectly when I replace input_file with a single file. But how would I get it to preform the some effect as grep -r "TEXT" *? I tried just putting input_file as * but it errors since it doesn't look into directories.

Comment: Ok that seems to work. \@GROUP should never exist without \@END_GROUP but the first one gave me a huge amount of gibberish like:
    <°☃e┌d ┼▒└e="┴┌d├_⎽├▒⎼├_☃d">SIH_STARTING_ID</°☃e┌d>
Which is odd. But the second option seemed to work ok (though my tmux window freaked out with the first one so I'll have to restart that I think).

Also, is there a way to have the files printed out before the lines? Right now I can't tell what file each line is from.

Comment: @JediWolf: maybe `grep -lr @GROUP /path/to/dir | while read file ; do sed -e '/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/!d' -e "s@^@$file:@" "$file" | grep '_START' ; done` ?

Comment: That worked! I don't think I ever would have figured that out on my own. The stuff in your original post maybe, but this just looks crazy to me. :P But it works, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can use null `RS` and do all that in single search:

```
awk -v RS= '/@GROUP.*_START.*@END_GROUP/' file
// @GROUP GroupName OtherStuff
#define GROUPNAME_START 1
#define GROUPNAME_FOO 2
.... (more defines)
#define GROUPNAME_END 10
// @END_GROUP
```

Comment: This works great to show the entire group, but how would I modify it to recursively search through directories so I don't have to do one file at a time? I don't think I made that clear in my initial question, I edited it to add in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `sed`, using its address syntax:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/@GROUP/h  # store the @GROUP line

/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/{
/_START/{
g  # retrieve the @GROUP line
n  # print it and continue
}
}

# otherwise, delete the line and continue
d
```

It's a little bit complicated by the nested blocks, but what this does is: within `@GROUP`..`@END_GROUP`, then for any line matching `_START` it will print the previously found `@GROUP` line thus (using your example):

```
$ ./group.sed group.data 
// @GROUP GroupName OtherStuff
```

Is that what you're trying to achieve?

**Edit**: It's not what you asked for - you just want the `_START` line, not the `@GROUP` line.  Well that's much easier:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
/@GROUP/,/@END_GROUP/{
/_START/p
}
```

**Addendum**: Since you now ask for recursive directory searching, you can use `find` as described in other answers:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ./group.sed --separate
```

(I've used the GNU sed `--separate` argument here to protect against any file having the group start but missing the group end line).

Comment: What could be done so the output also shows what file each line was found in?

Comment: That's more difficult, since the sed program doesn't really see the file name (it just sees the streamed content).  You could quickly knock up a wrapper shell script with something like `for f in "$@"; do ./group.sed $f | sed -e "s!^!${f//!/\\!}: !"; done`, I guess.